# traducir o encontrar el email que se envia para verificar email en Laravel 8 livewire

Tags: laravel

Llevo toda la tarde intentando encontrar el archivo o las cadenas de texto que se mandan en los emails para vertificar emails con laravel 8 livewire. necesito traducirlos

Alguien sabria orientarme?
gracias

Comment: Básicamente puedes escribir el asunto y el mensaje que quieras [Verification Email Customization](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification#customization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes hacer una publicación desde vendor.

Lo que quieres hacer esta en la carpeta vendor. Pero algunas versiones de laravel, cuando implemetas la interfaz mustVerifyEmail y has instalado la librería de auth, todos sus archivos, están dentro de la carpeta view/auth ahí encontrarás las view de resetPaswword, confirm, register, etc. Solo debes modificar los textos ahí.

Espero haberte ayudado.